# Why did my button activity cannot run me to the other page?

Tags: kotlin

This is my button.
I not sure if that my button have the problem or the kotlin files have the problem. The Home fragment is using binding to bind with the home fragment. Maybe is the intent in the fragment have the problem?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/registerbutton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:text="@string/register"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_design"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"
/>
```

This is my registration activity

```
class RegistrationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding:ActivityRegistrationBinding
    private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityRegistrationBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration)

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() // singleton

        binding.registerbutton.setOnClickListener{
            val fullName = binding.editText1.text.toString()
            val email = binding.editText2.text.toString()
            val password = binding.editText3.text.toString()

            val register = Register(fullName,email, password)

            // pass the User data obj to the firestore
            db.collection("Register").document("$email").set(register)

            intent = Intent(this, MainActivity:: class.java)

            Intent(this, HomeFragment:: class.java).putExtra("email",email)


            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }

    fun login(view: View) {
        intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity:: class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

This is my homefragment

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    //private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel (delete)
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        val intent = Intent(activity,RegistrationActivity::class.java)
        val email = intent.getStringExtra("email")

        db.collection("Register").document("$email").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { doc->
                binding.textViewName.text = doc.get("fullName").toString()
            }

            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e("Firestore", "Error in loading file: ${it.toString()}")
            }

        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't "open" a `Fragment` using the `startActivity` method. Fragments are meant to be embedded into activities as a part of the layout. Do you want to navigate to `MainActivity` or `LoginActivity` from `RegistrationActivity`?

Comment: i want to navigate to MainActivity from RegistrationActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the code in `RegistrationActivity` like this:

```
binding.registerbutton.setOnClickListener{
    val fullName = binding.editText1.text.toString()
    val email = binding.editText2.text.toString()
    val password = binding.editText3.text.toString()

    val register = Register(fullName,email, password)

    // pass the User data obj to the firestore
    db.collection("Register").document("$email").set(register)

    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity:: class.java)
    intent.putExtra("email", email)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Also, you should pass the data to the fragment using a `Bundle`:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("email", email)
homeFragment.arguments = bundle
```

And retrieve it in the fragment using the `arguments` object:

```
val email = arguments?.getString("email") ?: ""
```

Comment: May I know which activity should I put the Bundle in?

Comment: The activity containing the `HomeFragment`